# cannot get value from google sheet through app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm starting to learn how to code with Google App script and just completed the codelab playlist on Extending Google Sheets.

So to try it out I wrote a code with the intention of pulling a value from a specific cell from a sheet through a variable calles "OrderNum", using Logger to log the variable that would contain this value to check my code, but for some reason I keep getting an "(variable) is not defined)" error and I've tried multiple things already and nothing works... what I am doing wrong?? Here is my code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  // Create a custom menu
  ui.createMenu('Order Functions')
    .addItem('Copy form to database',"copy2db")
    .addToUi();
}

// Pull orderNum value from sheet
function checkOrderNum() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var orderNum = sheet.getRange('H2').getValue();
}

Logger.log('var ', orderNum);
```

[snippet of google sheet showing value of cell H2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKNms.png)

The error I'm getting is "ReferenceError: orderNum is not define). I don't get it, it seems to me that all the references are there. Also when I remove the logger command, no error appears but then I have no idea if my code is correct, which apparently isn't.

Thanks for the help,
Nestor

Comment: In your script, `Logger.log('var ', orderNum);` is put as the global. In this case, when a function is run, at first, `Logger.log('var ', orderNum);` is run without declaring `orderNum`. By this, such error occurs. If you want to see the value of `orderNum` at the log, how about including `Logger.log('var %s', orderNum);` in the last line of the function of `checkOrderNum()` by modifying `'var '` to `'var %s'`? By this, when `checkOrderNum()` is run, you can see the value at the log. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: thanks for the help @Tanaike!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error message : "ReferenceError: orderNum is not define).

This is because your Logger statement is not part of a function.

[Logger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger) is a feature of Google scripts and [Logger.log](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#logdata) is well documented.

In the following example, I have included three versions of a Logger statement.

- `Logger.log("the order number is "+orderNum);`: in this case the description text is in quotes, followed by the "+" operator and the variable name.
- `Logger.log('var %s', orderNum);`: the suggestion made by @Tanaike. In the case, '%s' acts as a placeholder [doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#logformat,-values).
- `Logger.log('var ', orderNum);`: this is your logger statement, but this time it is included within the function.

These statements return these results:

- the order number is 1001
- var 1001.0
- var  1001.0

---

```
// Pull orderNum value from sheet
function checkOrderNum() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var orderNum = sheet.getRange('H2').getValue();
  Logger.log("the order number is "+orderNum);
  Logger.log('var %s', orderNum);
  Logger.log('var ', orderNum);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tedinoz, this makes sense!